# Proof that for any face $F\neq P$ of a convex polytope is contained in a face OF dimension $\text{dim} F+1$.

Tags: polytopes, convex-geometry

Consider a convex polytope $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ as the convex hull of a minimal finite set $V$ whose elements are called "vertices", or equivalently as the bounded intersection of a finite collection of half-spaces.

A half-space is defined as $H^{\color{red}{\le}}:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}\mid c^{T}x\color{red}{\le} \delta,\, \delta\in\mathbb{R},\,c\in\mathbb{R}^{d}\setminus\{0\}\}$. Any hyperplane $H:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}\mid c^{T}x= \delta,\, \delta\in\mathbb{R},\,c\in\mathbb{R}^{d}\setminus\{0\}\}$ defines two half-spaces. A half-space containing $P$ is said valid for $P$.

A face $F$ of $P$ is the intersection between a valid half-space and $P$, which gives a set of the form $\{x\in P\mid c^{T}x= \delta,\, \delta\in\mathbb{R},\,c\in\mathbb{R}^{d}\setminus\{0\}\}$ or $P$ itself. The dimension of a face $F$ is the dimension of the affine hull of $F$.

With the above informations only (no other result on polytopes), we want to prove that any face $F\neq P$ is contained in some face $G$ with $\text{dim } G=\text{dim } F+1$.

The problem is I cannot understand how to begin. Even if I admit that a vertex is a face, I do not get how I can prove the existence of any proper face... I don't ask for a full resolution, only for hints on how to begin with such a problem. Thank you.

Comment: I think something was off there; double check (I thought it easier just to do than comment). Have you tried looking in any references? If you know that H- and V-representations of polytopes are equivalent, it shouldn't be much harder than just removing an inequality. But with convex hulls only, it seems like you need to show that there are no "jumps" in dimension...

Comment: If you speak about the dimension, yes it is better as it is corrected, now. Thank you. Aah I see... As there exists a minimal system of, say, $n$ inequalities, if I take $d$ equalities, either the intersection of the hyperplanes they are associated with is empty, either it defines a vertex. Now, if I remove one equality, I obtain a face containing the vertex and of superior dimension. Since the initial system of inequalities is minimal, these hyperplanes associated with the remaining $d-1$ equalities are not parallel and as their intersection is not empty (contains the vertex) ...\...

Comment: .../... it is necessarily a space of dimension $d-(d-1)=1$, so that the induced face is of dimension $1$. Repeating by removing $2,3,\dots,d-1$ equalities yield the desired chain of faces $F_{i}\subsetneq F_{i+1}$ where $\text{dim} f_{i}=i\,\forall\,i=-1,0,1,\dots,d$. If my reasoning is correct, do I miss some important subtilities ?

Comment: While I'm a fan of polytopes, rarely do I work with them in this manner so I'm afraid I can't verify the argument (although it sounds at least like the right sort of thing). I'm sure you can find the result in something like Ziegler or Grünbaum, probably even Coxeter or McMullen&Schulte.

Comment: @pjs36 Thanks for your reply. I checked some of these references and they don't show the proof (or deduce it as a corollary to some theorem proved with poset or other structure I don't know). However, I think your original idea is good: I shall try to write a nice proof.